# What is the best practice to change a single object in Angular component in a reactive way

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

Assuming I have an http request to get users:

```js
users$: Observable<User[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  users$ = this.users_service.get_all_users();
}
```

I subscribe to this observable using async pipe in my template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
```

I want to change an email of a single user with another http request, **but keep a single subscription**. The problem is that the http request that changes the email hasn't been defined at the point I created `users$` observable.
what I did is:

```js
users$: Observable<User[]>;
update_user_event$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
users_with_updates$: Observable<User[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  users$ = this.users_service.get_all_users();

  users_with_updates$ = Observable.combineLatest(users$, update_user_event$)
  .switchMap(([users, update_user_event]) => {
    return Observable.of(users)
  })
}
update_user(user) {
  this.user_service.update_user(user)
  .toPromise() // <== I don't want to subscribe to this request. Is there a way to combine it with `users$` without subscribing?
  .then(updated_user => {
    for(let key of user) {
      user[key] = updated_user[key]
    }
    update_user_event$.next(null);
  })
}
```

As you can see I subscribe to `update_user` using `toPromise()`. I can not combine this request ahead since it is not defined until it is requested.
I have been searching all over the internet but couldn't find an agreed best practice.
How do you think it should be done?
Thanks

Comment: To rephrase it, you want that an update on a user triggers the same `users$` observable so that your components get notified when you update an user?

Comment: I am not sure. I want to change a single user using an HTTP request in a reactive approach. I assumed it can be done using only one subscription with the async pipe but I am not sure that's possible so I would like to hear a professional opinion on how it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to store the users in a subject. The initial call as well any update will call `next` on the BehaviorSubject.

```
private users: BehaviorSubject<User[]> = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);
users$: Observable<User[]> = this.users.asObservable();

ngOnInit() {
  this.users_service.get_all_users().subscribe(this.users);
}

update_user(user) {
  this.user_service.update_user(user)
  .toPromise()
  .then(user => {
    const currentUsers = this.users.value;
    // TODO: change user in currentUsers
    this.users.next(currentUsers);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
But isn't it a bad practice to subscribe to the update_user request using toPromise() instead of somehow merging it to users$ observable and use a single subscription for both requests?